# Plotting with Logarithmic Scale

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Perhaps this is trivial but I would like to plot the following function:

\begin{equation}
p(t)=e^{\left( -\frac{d}{1-c}\right)\left[ W_0\left[B(1+x/r)^{1/d}\right]-W_0[B] \right]}
\end{equation}
where $W_k$ is the Lambert-W function for the $k=0$ branch and 
\begin{equation}
B=\frac{(1-c)r}{1-(1-c)r}e^{\frac{(1-c)r}{1-(1-c)r}}
\end{equation}
by the same way they are done in the attached picture below. I am not really sure how to make a $(\log p(x),x)$ plot, but I guess that if I could do one, the $(-\log p(x),x)$ plot would be by ploting $p^{-1}(x)$?
[image: Plots of $p(x)]

My *(poor)* attempt so far is the following:

```
c = 0.99999
r = 0.0001
  B = ((1 - c) r)/(1 - (1 - c) r) Exp[((1 - c) r)/(1 - (1 - c) r)]
   p = Table[ Exp[(-1/(1 - c)) (ProductLog[0, B*(1 + x/r)^(1/1)] - 
   ProductLog[0, B])], {d, 0.5, 2, 0.1}];
   LogPlot[Evaluate[p^-1, {x, 0, 10}], PlotRange -> {10^-1, 10^2}]
```

But even for the first one I am not able to get them correct.

I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Make `p` a function instead of a table maybe?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thank you for your answer. Please bear with me, I am still a newbie to Mathematica, therefore could you explain what should I try in a more detailed way? Again, I know that it may be trivial for many people in this forum but I am kind of struggling with it..

Comment: @Mitscaype Where do those plots come from originally?

Comment: @MarcoB  It is a paper I am studying, from Stephan Thurner and Rudolf Hanel: "What do generalized entropies look like? An axiomatic approach for complex, non-ergodic systems". But I am finding some different definition as far as their $p(x)$ is concerned when I try to derive it on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this to define `p` as a function:

```
Clear[p]
p[x_, c_, d_, r_] := Module[{B},
  B = ((1 - c) r)/(1 - (1 - c) r) Exp[(1 - c) r/(1 - (1 - c) r)];
  Exp[-d/(1 - c) (ProductLog[0, B*(1 + x/r)^(1/d)] - ProductLog[0, B])]
]
```

Then something like this to plot multiple instances as a function of different parameter choices:

```
LogLogPlot[
  {
    p[x, 0.2, 0.025, 0.9/(1 - 0.2)],
    p[x, 0.6, 0.025, 0.9/(1 - 0.6)],
    p[x, 0.8, 0.025, 0.9/(1 - 0.8)]
  },
  {x, 10^-5, 10^9}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, however, that I am not sure that your function definition correctly reproduces the values I can infer from the plots you showed. I am also worried about possible issues with numerical precision in your calculations involving very large / very small numbers.

---

Here is a similar idea for the first plot:

```
LogLogPlot[
  {
    -Log[p[x, 0.99999, 0.5, 1*^-4]],
    -Log[p[x, 0.99999, 1, 1*^-4]],
    -Log[p[x, 0.99999, 2, 1*^-4]]
  },
  {x, 10^-5, 10^9}, PlotRange -> {5*^-6, 1*^4},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green},
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
  PlotRangePadding -> {None, {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.15]}},
  Epilog -> {
    Inset[
      Style["c=0.99999\nr=0.0001", Black],
      ImageScaled[{0.18, 0.8}], Alignment -> Left
    ],
    Inset[Style["d=0.5", Black], ImageScaled[{0.43, 0.9}]],
    Inset[Style["d=1.0", Black], ImageScaled[{0.66, 0.9}]],
    Inset[Style["d=2.0", Black], ImageScaled[{0.93, 0.8}]]
  }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have two questions: As I see that you were able to reproduce the second plot, and I can see that you used a LogLog plot, how would you do it on the first plot that one of the axes is $-logp(x)$? Moreover, concerning your last statement, are the results of this $p(x)$ I defined not compatible with the plot values which are shown on my question? Again, thank you.

Comment: @Mitscaype As I understand it, the `-Log[p]` should be a straightforward extension of the first method, i.e. you use `LogLogPlot` to plot the value of $-\log{p(x)}$ on a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Thank you again for your help! It is very important for me, since I can maybe do the math but I can't manage it so well when it comes to plotting. One last question, how can one put the labels of $c,d$ and $r$ on the plot?

Comment: @Mitscaype Labels can be added using e.g. `Epilog` and `Inset`. Take a look at the last plot, which now includes labels; you should be able to modify the corresponding code to adjust to your liking.

Comment: It works perfectly now! Once again many thanks!